# Import csv from google cloud storage to google app script / google spreadsheet

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-cloud-storage

We are doing a project which we need to add a csv file from google cloud storage to a google sheet using google app script.

Any information on how to do this is using the link below but the example is only from google drive to google app script.

https://ctrlq.org/code/20279-import-csv-into-google-spreadsheet

Comment: Here's a tip...Read the google cloud storage documentation. All the information you need to get your project off the ground is there. If you're not sure where to start I'd suggest focusing on anything API related. Do some research, write some code, put some work in and then come back with any questions.

Comment: Also checkout [Utilities.parseCsv](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities)